# Why was my flag on a link-only answer declined?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, specific-answer, moderators, link-only-answers

I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74627883/965146) as Very Low Quality due to it being a link-only answer, since I thought it didn’t have any value if the link went dead.

I am not complaining about the declined flag; I'm just curious why it was declined.

The answer is now deleted. Here is a screenshot for under 10k:

[image: Sample_Image]

Comment: Mabey the mod thought that the text for the link was enought

Comment: did you use *Advanced Flagging* option *Link Only* to flag it?

Comment: @Vickel yep, why ?

Comment: because then it looks to me to be a mod mistake

Comment: it seems NAA flags are preferred over VLQ flags, while the latter is issued by the *Advanced Flagginf* script.

Comment: There is (at least for me) a quite confusing CW Meta Post [When to flag an answer as "not an answer"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer): *If there's nothing in the answer itself to actually answer the question, then it's not an answer and should be deleted.* VERSUS *Notice that this is not necessarily the same thing as a "link-only answer" (although there is much overlap). In particular, answers where the link itself is the answer to the question are excluded and should not be flagged.*

Comment: We handle VLQ and NAA more-or-less identically.  I'm guessing that the handling moderator considered "Specify symbol (.pdb) and source files in the Visual Studio debugger (C#, C++, Visual Basic, F#)" to be an answer, with the link being supplemental.  I've pinged them to confirm.

Comment: @RyanM thanks for pointing out the VLQ NAA handling. What's your opinion about the CW Meta Post I mentioned, for me this is really unclear...

Comment: " it had no value if the link was dead" is *not* the NAA ("possible answer with no value" vs. "not an answer to anything"), it could be reason for downvote...

Comment: @Vickel the litmus test is: if the link is stripped/removed, do you get any insight from the answer, however small it is?

Comment: @Vickel As Andrew says, quoting from [that post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265553/208273): "A handy rule-of-thumb is to strip the markup: if it's still an (attempted) answer without the link, then it's an answer and should not be flagged."

Comment: It looks like there's an answer there. In fact, apart from there being a link in the answer, the text of the linked answer seems to be saying pretty much the same thing as the other 2 answers on the question. If the linked answer is NAA, then so are the others.

Comment: I agree with @cigien here. The two undeleted answers say the same this (set PDB as symbol), without any commentary. This answer at least links to a reference page. I didn't flag, but did leave my canned link-only comment, in the hope they would add more information, since it seemed, without looking at the other answers, that setting this symbol would not be so trivial. Thus, that the linked page would explain how to actually do that. All in all, it seems to me a better answer than the two undeleted ones, because the solution is exactly the same and this at least has a relevant link.

Comment: I edited the link from the deleted link-only answer into the first and top-rated answer. Now everyone can be satisfied, or more likely even more mad.

Comment: If we are deeming Link-only answers like this to be unworthy of space on Stack Overflow, are we yet going to agree that link-only-function-only answers which point to the documentation are the least helpful type of "correct" answer?  I would love it if mods would sweep through and convert all of the "[explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)" and "[json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode)" answers that do not even bother showing how to implement the function with the question details. It's not too late to clean up old content.

Comment: Link only answers should, in my opinion, always be flagged because the content behind the link can either change or be removed completely.

Comment: In my opinion it depends on what you're linking to. Some resources, such as RFCs are likely to be around long after StackOverflow is dead. And where the question is explicitly asking for a reference ("Where is it specified that....") then it's hard to add anything to the link other than pure noise designed to satisfy moderators.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Sorry about this.

What has happened was that I used the standard Stack Overflow flag queue. It doesn't show the full post, only a text summary. I didn't know it was a link. It looked like an attempt at answering.

Now that I saw it was actually just a link, I would have deleted it. The text is actually a title of the linked article so it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Thanks for honest reply. No need to sorry, I just curious  what happen here.

Comment: Out of curiosity, *"I used the standard Stack Overflow flag queue"* - as opposed to what?

Comment: @Tomerikoo As opposed to actually opening the flagged post.

Comment: Quite unsettling to see a moderator reply along the lines of: *That's the outcome **I** would have hoped for, so let's just encourage you (and everyone else) to take the wrong actions"*...

Comment: @IInspectable What do you mean wrong actions?

Comment: You've commented on my answer, so I would assume you've actually read it. It explains why flagging was the wrong option.

Comment: @IInspectable Perhaps we have some misunderstanding here. I declined it because I didn't know it was a title of an article. The title might give some clue as to how to solve the issue, but we generally don't allow answers that just say "go read this, there's your solution". Improving this answer would be a good option too, but flagging it wasn't the wrong action IMHO.

Comment: *"I declined it because I didn't know it was a title of an article"* - There you have it. Apparently the title was enough to not see it as a link-only answer. I wonder why you're still arguing that it should have been flagged as such. Again, I'm not voicing my *personal* opinions on the subject, just re-iterating site rules. Do moderators not care anymore?

Comment: @IInspectable We're not robots. Not everything is always black or white. Sometimes things are in the grey area. Either flagging or not flagging would be the correct action. However, my declining it was not the right thing to do.

Comment: No one is expecting you to be a robot. Though, the part that *is* unsettling is that you applied the *"handy rule-of-thumb [...] to strip the markup"*, and concluded that the subject was indeed an answer, only to later change your mind: *"Oh, hey, this is actually rendered in <whatever color>, so this cannot be an answer, even though I thought it was when it was rendered using <some other color>"*. That's quite problematic when coming from a moderator.

Comment: @IInspectable No, I changed my mind after seeing that the text wasn't the author's suggestion on how to solve the issue but rather the title of the article. It changed my opinion in regards to the flag, but it doesn't change the rules.

Comment: @Dharman What difference does it make whether the text was the author's attempt at an answer or the title of an article they're linking to? Are you saying that if someone left that text and didn't hyperlink it, that would be an okay answer to leave on Stack Overflow? But if they turn that text into a hyperlink, that suddenly makes it not OK to leave as an answer?

Comment: @mason It makes a difference to me whether to decline the flag or mark it helpful. If the link was there just as additional information then I would decline it; and the answer can be deleted by 20k users. But here there was no original content. The text was not the solution. It could have just been "Solution: click here". Seeing this I understood why someone decided to flag it.

Comment: That makes no sense to me. If you saw the text alone without the hyperlink, and thought it was okay to leave on the site, then why would seeing it as a hyperlink suddenly make it not okay? Not that I think this type of answer is acceptable at all, but my point is that BOTH scenarios should have been deleted and the flag marked as helpful. When we get garbage presented to us and don't take action to clean it up, that just means more people have to get involved to clean it up, and so it's less likely to actually get cleaned up. Three different 20K users would have to get involved to clean up.

Comment: Because I could not have known that it was garbage without this extra information. Mods don't evaluate the correctness of an answer.

Comment: The way I see it, the fact that the link was there only allowed Dharman to realise the text wasn't an attempt at an answer but the title of the link itself. Without the link, if someone found out it was a copy paste, then it would have been some kind of low quality plagiarism.

Comment: *"Because I could not have known that it was garbage"* - Not trying to be rude here, but dude, a proposed answer—**any** proposed answer—that doesn't identify the **issue** is complete garbage. You don't have to be a domain expert to know this much. This should be obvious. What strikes me as odd is how you can both claim that *"Mods don't evaluate the correctness"* and *"it was garbage [so deleting it as a link-only answer is well justified]"*. Care to explain how to resolve **that** contradiction?

Comment: @IInspectable No, sorry, because I don't understand your confusion anymore. I feel like I explained my actions here pretty clearly. If you have a broader disagreement with the process of handling NAA/VLQ flags, maybe you should post another Meta question.

Comment: *It doesn't show the full post, only a text summary.* Looks like a bug... What is wrong with showing links in blue even in summaries?

Comment: @kesarlingHe-Him Because Stack Exchange Inc. has no interest in making basic improvements to basic moderation tools, because that would allow more trash to be deleted, and that's bad for the bottom line.

Comment: Clarification question: would you consider "*Solution: Specify symbol (.pdb) and source files in the Visual Studio debugger (C#, C++, Visual Basic, F#). [See this](link)*" as a NAA as well? All I've changed here is separated out the original link from the text of the answer and put it inside an additional "see this" (which makes it virtually identical to the other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71751441/)). I'm trying to understand where you're drawing the line. Is the problem that there's a link at all, or that the link encapsulates the text of the answer?

Comment: @cigien That is still no original content. The author needs to write their own solution and use link only as a supportive documentation.

Comment: @Dharman I see. That the lack of original content was a relevant factor wasn't clear from your answer, at least to me. Also, it's not *mandatory* that an answer have original content, is it? So long as the copied content is not the entirety of the linked material, the copied content is tailored to the question, and attribution is clear, that's permissible in an SO answer I thought. And wouldn't this require an explanation in a flag anyway? I can see a mod deleting the linked answer for various reasons (even just as a regular user with delete privileges), but it doesn't seem eligible for NAA.

Comment: Even the fact that the linked answer doesn't add anything useful over the existing answers is a good reason to delete it. However, the standard policy for NAA is that the answer itself should be clearly not an attempt to answer, and if there's any other reasons to delete the answer, it should be custom flagged. The impression given by your answer is that such answers are eligible for a standard NAA flag, which seems to me a risky thing to suggest.

Comment: @cigien You are right. However, the documentation says that an answer should contain original content. The community sometimes turns the blind eye on this if it's reasonable. A custom flag with a proper explanation is always better.

Answer (score -19):

Not every answer that consists of a hyperlink only will entirely become useless if the link target becomes temporarily or permanently inaccessible.

In this case, the hyperlink text holds instructions: *"Specify symbol (.pdb) and source files in the Visual Studio debugger"* that remain useful even without the link.

While I don't think that this is an example of a quality contribution, that's arguably a reason to decline the link-only flag.

There's a related [community wiki](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265552/1889329) with an [answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265553/1889329) that summarizes *"What NOT To Flag"*:

> **Any post that attempts to answer the question — however badly — is still an answer**! Do not use the "not an answer" flag for wrong answers. Moderators do not judge the technical correctness of answers.
>
> You can downvote such answers as a signal that they are bad answers and not useful, but they are still answers, so you should not flag them.

That seems to be the case here: A **really** poor answer that's still an answer.

Valid options here are (and this just is repeating site rules, not necessarily my opinions on how things *should* work):

- Try to improve it, and/or
- Vote on it

Comment: The link title in itself doesn't answer this question in my opinion. It seems to be the first step to solving the problem, but it is incomplete, and thus the answer itself still is in another castle, which does make it link only. Especially if you consider that the linked article is about 3 or 4 pages of instructions and explanation.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel It is a poor answer, but still an answer. This is a case for the voting system (not the moderation system).

Comment: OP says they've flagged as VLQ, the instructions in this answer are for NAA.

Comment: While you are correct, I would have still deleted it if I saw that it was just a link. The text is the title of the linked article so it isn't really the solution, because someone would still have to look up how to do it in that article.

Comment: @Teemu From the community wiki answer: *"there is much overlap"*, so I believe this is applicable still. If you feel differently, please explain why things are subtly or obviously different.

Comment: @Dharman It may not be an answer to folks who haven't used Windows debuggers much. To someone that's used a Windows debugger virtually every single day of the past few decades, there's a lot more value to read out of the link title. Though that pretty much boils down to an age-old issue with SO as a whole: It doesn't make a difference between domain experts and everyone else.

Comment: But don't the other two answers already say the same thing?

Comment: @Dharman *All* proposed answers are garbage. I don't see why one should be treated differently from the others.

Comment: One way of looking at the situation is that it's treated differently because there's another rule we can apply to get low-quality stuff deleted: link-only answers.  Especially where the answer text is just the title of an article, so the author just copy/pasted that instead of writing anything themselves.  On the assumption that the article is actually helpful, though, I commented with a link to it under the earliest (and only upvoted) answer.  If @Dharman had initially realized it was a link, conversion to a comment could have worked, or someone else should have commented with the link.

Comment: "It's still an answer so it must be left alone to be dealt with by votes" is the most stupidly facetious non-argument that ever became codified into Stack Overflow moderation practices, and is arguably one of the reasons the site's quality went so steeply downhill. Low-effort trash is trash, and trash belongs in the bin, not here. Stop obstructing efforts to delete it by saying "but that there is trash too so you should delete it too", if you follow that insanity to its conclusion you never end up deleting _any_ trash - which is far worse than deleting "only" one piece of it.

Comment: @Dharman I just ran an experiment, and flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71751441/1889329) (which, as you've concluded, is pretty much the same as the one you felt should have been flagged). Result: *"declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it"* Can you explain that?

Comment: Correct. Why should this one be deleted. I don't understand why you would think this is not an answer

Comment: @Dharman Right. So why should the other (identical) answer then have gotten different treatment? Why would you judge one as flag-worthy but not the other? Are you just speaking for yourself or is this the general stance of all moderators?

Comment: @IInspectable Because the other one was nothing but the link. It didn't contain any original content. It was just a link to an article. The other answer you flagged here is a solution from whomever wrote the answer with the link used only as supportive information to see more. Link-only answers are not answers and should be deleted.

Comment: @Dharman *"It didn't contain any original content"* - That's not a metric to decide whether a contribution is a link-only answer or not. If you are struggling this much understand what is and isn't a link-only answer, can't you have a fellow moderator clue you in?